# How to make the image when clicked goes to the product detail permalink?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some confusion when editing the CSS code in WordPress to display a link to the permalink product details in WordPress. Is there a friend who can help me? This is my code.

```html
<article id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="productbox">

<div class="content">           
<div class="image productbox-image lazy" data-bg="url(<?php echo $thumb;?>)" >
<?php if ($promo == 'on') : ?>
<span class="ribbon">Promo</span>
<?php endif; ?>       
</div>

<div class="detail">
<?php
the_title('<h3><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>');
?>
<div class="desc">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<div class="pricing">
    <?php
    echo $prices;
    ?>
</div>
```

Thank you before

Comment: can you add full code? with what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing that `<div>` for image to an `<a>` and include the permalink in the `href` of it.

Eg:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" class="image productbox-image lazy" data-bg="url(<?php echo $thumb;?>)" >
<?php if ($promo == 'on') : ?>
<span class="ribbon">Promo</span>
<?php endif; ?>       
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know how specific the CSS selectors are for the div which has

`class="image productbox-image lazy" data-bg="url(<?php echo $thumb;?>)"`

to ensure the CSS formatting stays the same for it we'll have to keep it as a div.

What we can do though is wrap it in an anchor element with href the permalink to the details.

```
<a href="<?php  echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
<div class="image productbox-image lazy" data-bg="url(<?php echo $thumb;?>)" >
<?php if ($promo == 'on') : ?>
<span class="ribbon">Promo</span>
<?php endif; ?>       
</div>
</a>
```